# NSData never being released

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I have this code to convert an NSData object filled with RGB data into an NSData object filled with RGBA data that will then be converted to an image and displayed.  Unfortunately Instruments shows my memory steadily climbing and that it's my rgbaData object in the below code that never goes away.

```
- (NSData *)uint8RGBADataOfSize:(NSUInteger)size fromRGBData:(NSData *)rgbData
{
    NSMutableData *rgbaData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:(size * 4  * sizeof(uint8_t))];
    uint8_t *rgba = rgbaData.mutableBytes;
    const uint8_t *rgb = rgbData.bytes;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        rgba[4*i+0] = rgb[3*i];
        rgba[4*i+1] = rgb[3*i+1];
        rgba[4*i+2] = rgb[3*i+2];
        rgba[4*i+3] = 255;
    }

    return rgbaData;
}
```

I call the above method like so:

```
data = [self uint8RGBADataOfSize:(width * height) fromRGBData:data];
```

Data is my original NSData with rgb data, and I just replace it with my newly created rgba NSData before creating an image out of it:

```
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(nil, data.bytes, totalBytes, nil);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo, provider, nil, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
```

My new data isn't used after creating the above provider, and my method exists shortly after this when I pass a UIImage back out.  Everything here looks good to me, but I end up with an ever increasing horde of Malloc 84.00 KB's that come from my `uint8RGBADataOfSize:fromRGBData:` method.  At this point I'm stumped, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try making data a property, and set it to nil after use: self.data = nil;  This might help lead to where your problem is, especially if you still have leaks.

Comment: @OwenHartnett Thanks for the suggestion, but the original data comes from a passed in object, I just create a local pointer to it so I can overwrite it with the above code if my data object is RGB data.  It could be GreyScale which doesn't need conversion.  But while I didn't do the property syntax I did try adding a data=nil after my provider creation call to no effect.

Comment: Even though you're using ARC, you can still call retainCount on your objects.  p (int) [data retainCount]  in the console will show you the current number of retainCounts still on your data.

Comment: Not sure what I'm seeing but in my method rgbaData goes from 1 retain count on creation to 2 when I grab the mutableBytes pointer, but that shouldn't cause any retains.  External to the method data goes from 3 to 4 to 3 around the provider creation and reference releases.

Comment: I have the same problem!!
When assigning data.bytes to a uint8_t *, the retain count increases but never decreases!

When I read the documentation, it indicates that it should be a weak reference: `For an immutable data object, the returned pointer is valid until the data object is deallocated. For a mutable data object, the returned pointer is valid until the data object is deallocated or the data is mutated.`

Comment: I never revisited this, but I eventually found my problem, and it was that my original data object was being created in a thread that wasn't in an autorelease pool, and so it stuck around forever.  Not sure if that helps you @ShravyaBoggarapu

Comment: @RobBooth Well, I resolved my issue in a way. This NSData had 2 places where leak occured. I fixed the first one but I hadn't passed it through leak check since I hadn't fixed this one. But, on running through leaks, I saw that there are no leaks. I obtained retain count through `CFGetRetainCount()` function and it still shows that retain count increased and never decreased but I guess in the end it did not matter to the ARC if it is not a pointer of NS**** type